# SOLR DIH delta import vs Update

Tags: c#, .net, solr, solrj, solrnet

I have a large data stored in a SQL database that is being updated constantly. I need to find the best way to update Solr index noting that i have too many table(s) relations, for example Product, ProductDetails, ProductStocks ... etc.

There seems to be two solution for this:

1) DIH deltaQueryImport - query the database for all records that have LastUpdated greater than the last_index_time and then Import those records for indexing to Solr, the DIH is scheduled every 30 minutes, and the data during the sceduled is not yet reflected, too much time is spent on queries due to the number of records updated.

2) Task Queue - every time a product is updated in the database, we queue a task to index that record to Solr.

Just want to know your recommendation and the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a project with similar scenario. We decide to implemented your 2nd solution. 
Push is preferable than pull solution. With push solution, you can achieve near real time update, usually that's a big plus for business.

But with this solution, you need to consider the following:

1. Batch initial load.
2. Size of queue if you have a batch update.