# Solr 8 full-import working, but delta import fails to update fields

Tags: solr, delta

**the important part of my data-config**

```
<document name="cities">        
    <entity pk="id" name="city" 
    query="SELECT DISTINCT latitude,longitude
    ,MAX(gc.id) AS id
    ,ISNULL(MAX(geonameid),0) AS geonameid
    ,MAX(name) AS name
    ,MAX(name_en) AS name_en
    ,MAX(alternate_names) AS alternate_names
    ,MAX(updatedate) as updatedate
    FROM geo_cities gc 
    WHERE latitude &lt;&gt; '' AND longitude &lt;&gt; '' AND [country code] &lt;&gt; ''
    GROUP BY latitude,longitude"        
    deltaImportQuery="SELECT DISTINCT latitude,longitude
    ,MAX(gc.id) AS id
    ,ISNULL(MAX(geonameid),0) AS geonameid
    ,MAX(name) AS name
    ,MAX(name_en) AS name_en
    ,MAX(alternate_names) AS alternate_names
    ,MAX(updatedate) as updatedate
    FROM geo_cities gc 
    WHERE updatedate &lt; getdate() AND gc.id=${dataimporter.delta.id}      
    GROUP BY latitude,longitude"
    deltaQuery="SELECT id,alternate_names FROM geo_cities WHERE updatedate &gt; '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">
        
        <field name="id" column="id" />
        <field name="geonameid" column="geonameid" />
        <field name="name" column="name" />
        <field name="name_en" column="name_en" />
        <field name="alternate_names" column="alternate_names" />
        <field name="longitude" column="LONGITUDE" />
        <field name="latitude" column="LATITUDE" />

    </entity>
</document>
```

When I run a full import like so: http://localhost:8983/solr/cities/dataimport?command=full-import
everything gets indexed correctly.

Then when directly in my database I change the column value of "alternate_names" and also update column "updatedate" to a more recent date for a single row and then run a delta-import query like so: http://localhost:8983/solr/cities/dataimport?command=delta-import

I see this output:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2},
  "initArgs":[
    "defaults",[
      "config","data-config.xml"]],
  "command":"delta-import",
  "status":"idle",
  "importResponse":"",
  "statusMessages":{
    "Total Requests made to DataSource":"5",
    "Total Rows Fetched":"5",
    "Total Documents Processed":"1",
    "Total Documents Skipped":"0",
    "Delta Dump started":"2022-07-08 21:57:06",
    "Identifying Delta":"2022-07-08 21:57:06",
    "Deltas Obtained":"2022-07-08 21:57:06",
    "Building documents":"2022-07-08 21:57:06",
    "Total Changed Documents":"1",
    "":"Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 1 documents. Deleted 0 documents.",
    "Committed":"2022-07-08 21:57:06",
    "Time taken":"0:0:0.148"}}
```

But If I then check via my Solr Admin UI and inspect the indexed fields like so: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/cities/query?q=*:*&q.op=OR&indent=true&fq=geonameid:111

I still see the OLD values for fields `alternate_names` and `updatedate`. Why are those not updated?

**UPDATE 1**

After doing some more research, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535514/solr-dih-delta-import-vs-update) that speaks about delta import vs task queueing (push), where push seems to be preferred for more real-time propagation of changes (which is what I want too).
I then found this documentation: https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/updatehandlers-in-solrconfig.html

However, I don't know if that solves for my issue, nor do the examples give me an idea where to even start.
PS. I DON'T use Solr Cloud.

**UPDATE 2**

When I try http://localhost:8983/solr/cities/update?commit=true it returns:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1}}
```

When I append `commit=true` to my regular delta-import: http://localhost:8983/solr/cities/dataimport?command=delta-import&commit=true it does not show anything was changed.

Weirdly, and different than my latest test, the `delta-import` url no longer shows the `committed` field, even though I have made changes to the `updatedate` field in my database.

I checked the logging, but don't see anything strange. Logging is all set to "WARN":

```
Log4j2
  root
WARN
  com
null
  codahale
null
  metrics
null
  jmx
null
  JmxReporter
WARN
  org
null
  apache
null
  calcite
null
  avatica
null
  remote
null
  Driver
WARN
  hadoop
WARN
  http
null
  client
null
  protocol
null
  RequestAddCookies
WARN
  RequestAuthCache
WARN
  RequestClientConnControl
WARN
  ResponseProcessCookies
WARN
  conn
null
  ssl
null
  AllowAllHostnameVerifier
WARN
  BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier
WARN
  DefaultHostnameVerifier
WARN
  SSLConnectionSocketFactory
WARN
  StrictHostnameVerifier
WARN
  headers
WARN
  impl
null
  auth
null
  HttpAuthenticator
WARN
  client
null
  DefaultRedirectStrategy
WARN
  InternalHttpClient
WARN
  ProxyAuthenticationStrategy
WARN
  TargetAuthenticationStrategy
WARN
  conn
null
  CPool
WARN
  DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator
WARN
  DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection
WARN
  execchain
null
  MainClientExec
WARN
  ProtocolExec
WARN
  RedirectExec
WARN
  RetryExec
WARN
  wire
WARN
  solr
null
  DEPRECATED
null
  solr
null
  SynonymFilterFactory
WARN
  WordDelimiterFilterFactory
WARN
  api
null
  AnnotatedApi
WARN
  ApiBag
WARN
  CustomContainerPlugins
WARN
  client
null
  solrj
null
  impl
null
  Http2SolrClient
WARN
  HttpClientUtil
WARN
  SolrHttpRequestRetryHandler
WARN
  io
null
  SolrClientCache
WARN
  routing
null
  RequestReplicaListTransformerGenerator
WARN
  cloud
null
  ActionThrottle
WARN
  common
null
  util
null
  ExecutorUtil
WARN
  IOUtils
WARN
  JavaBinCodec
WARN
  TimeSource
WARN
  Utils
WARN
  core
null
  BlobRepository
WARN
  CachingDirectoryFactory
WARN
  ConfigSetProperties
WARN
  ConfigSetService
WARN
  CoreContainer
WARN
  CoreDescriptor
WARN
  CorePropertiesLocator
WARN
  DirectoryFactory
WARN
  IndexDeletionPolicyWrapper
WARN
  MemClassLoader
WARN
  PluginBag
WARN
  QuerySenderListener
WARN
  RequestHandlers
WARN
  RequestParams
WARN
  SchemaCodecFactory
WARN
  SolrConfig
WARN
  SolrCore
WARN
  Request
WARN
  SlowRequest
INFO
  SolrCores
WARN
  SolrDeletionPolicy
WARN
  SolrPaths
WARN
  SolrResourceLoader
WARN
  SolrXmlConfig
WARN
  StandardDirectoryFactory
WARN
  TransientSolrCoreCacheDefault
WARN
  TransientSolrCoreCacheFactory
WARN
  XmlConfigFile
WARN
  ZkContainer
WARN
  backup
null
  repository
null
  BackupRepositoryFactory
WARN
  snapshots
null
  SolrSnapshotMetaDataManager
WARN
  filestore
null
  DistribPackageStore
WARN
  PackageStoreAPI
WARN
  handler
null
  ExportHandler
WARN
  GraphHandler
WARN
  PingRequestHandler
WARN
  ReplicationHandler
WARN
  RequestHandlerBase
WARN
  SQLHandler
WARN
  SchemaHandler
WARN
  SolrConfigHandler
WARN
  StreamHandler
WARN
  admin
null
  AdminHandlersProxy
WARN
  AutoscalingHistoryHandler
WARN
  CollectionsHandler
WARN
  ConfigSetsHandler
WARN
  CoreAdminHandler
WARN
  CoreAdminOperation
WARN
  HealthCheckHandler
WARN
  InvokeOp
WARN
  LoggingHandler
WARN
  LukeRequestHandler
WARN
  MergeIndexesOp
WARN
  MetricsCollectorHandler
WARN
  MetricsHistoryHandler
WARN
  PrepRecoveryOp
WARN
  RequestSyncShardOp
WARN
  SecurityConfHandler
WARN
  SecurityConfHandlerLocal
WARN
  SegmentsInfoRequestHandler
WARN
  ShowFileRequestHandler
WARN
  SplitOp
WARN
  SystemInfoHandler
WARN
  ZookeeperInfoHandler
WARN
  ZookeeperStatusHandler
WARN
  component
null
  FacetComponent
WARN
  HttpShardHandlerFactory
WARN
  MoreLikeThisComponent
WARN
  QueryComponent
WARN
  RealTimeGetComponent
WARN
  SearchHandler
WARN
  SpellCheckComponent
WARN
  dataimport
null
  DataImportHandler
WARN
  DataImporter
WARN
  DocBuilder
WARN
  EntityProcessorBase
WARN
  EntityProcessorWrapper
WARN
  JdbcDataSource
WARN
  SimplePropertiesWriter
WARN
  SolrWriter
WARN
  SqlEntityProcessor
WARN
  Zipper
WARN
  config
null
  DIHConfiguration
WARN
  loader
null
  JsonLoader
WARN
  XMLLoader
WARN
  highlight
null
  DefaultSolrHighlighter
WARN
  logging
null
  DeprecationLog
WARN
  LogWatcher
WARN
  log4j2
null
  Log4j2Watcher
WARN
  metrics
null
  MetricSuppliers
WARN
  MetricsMap
WARN
  SolrCoreMetricManager
WARN
  SolrMetricManager
WARN
  SolrMetricReporter
WARN
  reporters
null
  ReporterClientCache
WARN
  SolrJmxReporter
WARN
  jmx
null
  JmxMetricsReporter
WARN
  rrd
null
  SolrRrdBackend
WARN
  SolrRrdBackendFactory
WARN
  pkg
null
  PackageListeners
WARN
  request
null
  SolrRequestInfo
WARN
  response
null
  BinaryResponseWriter
WARN
  rest
null
  ManagedResource
WARN
  ManagedResourceStorage
WARN
  RestManager
WARN
  schema
null
  AbstractSpatialFieldType
WARN
  AbstractSpatialPrefixTreeFieldType
WARN
  BinaryField
WARN
  ClassicIndexSchemaFactory
WARN
  FieldType
WARN
  FieldTypePluginLoader
WARN
  IndexSchema
WARN
  IndexSchemaFactory
WARN
  PointField
WARN
  search
null
  CacheConfig
WARN
  CaffeineCache
WARN
  CollapsingQParserPlugin
WARN
  FastLRUCache
WARN
  PayloadCheckQParserPlugin
WARN
  SolrDocumentFetcher
WARN
  SolrIndexSearcher
WARN
  SurroundQParserPlugin
WARN
  TermsQParserPlugin
WARN
  join
null
  ChildFieldValueSourceParser
WARN
  stats
null
  LocalStatsCache
WARN
  servlet
null
  CheckLoggingConfiguration
WARN
  HttpSolrCall
INFO
  SolrDispatchFilter
WARN
  SolrRequestParsers
WARN
  spelling
null
  DirectSolrSpellChecker
WARN
  update
null
  CommitTracker
WARN
  DefaultSolrCoreState
WARN
  DirectUpdateHandler2
WARN
  LoggingInfoStream
OFF
  SolrCoreState
WARN
  SolrIndexConfig
WARN
  SolrIndexWriter
WARN
  TransactionLog
WARN
  UpdateHandler
WARN
  UpdateLog
WARN
  UpdateShardHandler
WARN
  VersionInfo
WARN
  processor
null
  AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory
WARN
  AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger
WARN
  DistributedUpdateProcessor
WARN
  FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor
WARN
  LogUpdateProcessorFactory
WARN
  ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory
WARN
  ParseDoubleFieldUpdateProcessorFactory
WARN
  ParseLongFieldUpdateProcessorFactory
WARN
  RoutedAliasUpdateProcessor
WARN
  UpdateRequestProcessor
WARN
  UpdateRequestProcessorChain
WARN
  util
null
  ConcurrentLRUCache
WARN
  SolrPluginUtils
WARN
  StartupLoggingUtils
WARN
  TestInjection
WARN
  circuitbreaker
null
  CPUCircuitBreaker
WARN
  MemoryCircuitBreaker
WARN
  configuration
null
  SSLConfigurations
WARN
  SSLCredentialProviderFactory
WARN
  plugin
null
  AbstractPluginLoader
WARN
  stats
null
  InstrumentedPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
WARN
  MetricUtils
WARN
  zookeeper
WARN
  eclipse
null
  jetty
null
  client
null
  AuthenticationProtocolHandler
WARN
  HttpClient
WARN
  HttpClientTransport
WARN
  HttpRedirector
WARN
  ResponseNotifier
WARN
  deploy
null
  AppLifeCycle
WARN
  DeploymentManager
WARN
  providers
null
  ScanningAppProvider
WARN
  WebAppProvider
WARN
  http
null
  HttpFields
WARN
  HttpGenerator
WARN
  HttpParser
WARN
  MimeTypes
WARN
  PreEncodedHttpField
WARN
  pathmap
null
  PathMappings
WARN
  ServletPathSpec
WARN
  http2
null
  HTTP2Connection
WARN
  hpack
null
  HpackContext
WARN
  HpackEncoder
WARN
  server
null
  HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory
WARN
  HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory
WARN
  io
null
  AbstractConnection
WARN
  AbstractEndPoint
WARN
  ChannelEndPoint
WARN
  FillInterest
WARN
  IdleTimeout
WARN
  ManagedSelector
WARN
  MappedByteBufferPool
WARN
  SelectorManager
WARN
  WriteFlusher
WARN
  rewrite
null
  handler
null
  RuleContainer
WARN
  security
null
  SecurityHandler
WARN
  server
null
  AbstractConnector
WARN
  CachedContentFactory
WARN
  CookieCutter
WARN
  Dispatcher
WARN
  HttpChannel
WARN
  HttpChannelOverHttp
WARN
  HttpChannelState
WARN
  HttpConfiguration
WARN
  HttpConnection
WARN
  HttpInput
WARN
  HttpOutput
WARN
  Request
WARN
  ResourceService
WARN
  Response
WARN
  Server
WARN
  handler
null
  AbstractHandler
WARN
  AbstractHandlerContainer
WARN
  ContextHandler
WARN
  solr
WARN
  ContextHandlerCollection
WARN
  DefaultHandler
WARN
  ErrorHandler
WARN
  InetAccessHandler
WARN
  ResourceHandler
WARN
  gzip
null
  GzipHandler
WARN
  GzipHttpOutputInterceptor
WARN
  session
WARN
  servlet
null
  BaseHolder
WARN
  DefaultServlet
WARN
  ErrorPageErrorHandler
WARN
  FilterHolder
WARN
  Holder
WARN
  ServletContextHandler
WARN
  ServletHandler
WARN
  ServletHolder
WARN
  listener
null
  ELContextCleaner
WARN
  util
null
  DecoratedObjectFactory
WARN
  DeprecationWarning
WARN
  IO
WARN
  Jetty
WARN
  ModuleLocation
WARN
  Pool
WARN
  Scanner
WARN
  SharedBlockingCallback
WARN
  SocketAddressResolver
WARN
  TypeUtil
WARN
  URIUtil
WARN
  Utf8Appendable
WARN
  component
null
  AbstractLifeCycle
WARN
  ContainerLifeCycle
WARN
  log
WARN
  resource
null
  JarFileResource
WARN
  JarResource
WARN
  PathResource
WARN
  Resource
WARN
  URLResource
WARN
  ssl
null
  SslContextFactory
WARN
  config
WARN
  thread
null
  QueuedThreadPool
WARN
  ReservedThreadExecutor
WARN
  ShutdownThread
WARN
  ThreadPoolBudget
WARN
  strategy
null
  EatWhatYouKill
WARN
  webapp
null
  JettyWebXmlConfiguration
WARN
  MetaData
WARN
  MetaInfConfiguration
WARN
  StandardDescriptorProcessor
WARN
  WebAppClassLoader
WARN
  WebAppContext
WARN
  WebDescriptor
WARN
  WebInfConfiguration
WARN
  WebXmlConfiguration
WARN
  xml
null
  XmlConfiguration
WARN
  XmlParser
 WARN
```

Comment: after running delta import, have you commied the documents?

Comment: Thanks. How exactly would I go about doing that? My output already says "Committed":"2022-07-08 21:57:06"`` but that's not enough I guess?

Comment: You can still add `commit=true` in the delta-import request to see if it makes a difference, but I think it's not the issue here, as the "Committed":"<datetime>" line is present in the output. It wouldn't if the `commit` parameter was explicitly set to `false` (it defaults to `true` for both full and delta import commands). Is there anything suspicious in the logs ? Do you see some changes if you tell Solr to commit all pending docs via the /update handler after the delta-import `http://localhost:8983/solr/cities/update?commit=true` ?

Comment: It could be that your commit strategy ([opensearcher vs soft commit](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_5/near-real-time-searching.html)) does not make the changes visible immediately. It could also be the index searcher's document cache if you have [lazy field loading](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_5/query-settings-in-solrconfig.html#enablelazyfieldloading) enabled.